# Boostrap 3 - col-md-4 to col-sm-6, or grid of 3x2 to 2x3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

How can I change a grid of 3x2 to 2x3 without having an empty space where one row ends and another starts?

For example:

```
 <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I want to achieve:

This:
[image]

To this: [image]

But instead I get this:[image]

Comment: What code are you using to change it? You've only provided the code for the initial orientation.

Comment: Just using bootstraps default media queries: col-md-4 and col-sm-6.  I didn't think I would need anything else. Works a treat for col-md-3 to col-sm-6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put it all in one row - it'll wrap down automatically.

```
 <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        content 6
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmwfbjs7/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Put them all in one row. See [**this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/mwb0fduChs)

Like:

```
<div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <span class="box">content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <span class="box">content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <span class="box">content</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <span class="box">content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <span class="box">content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <span class="box">content</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hadn't come across bootply before, nice one