# Bootstrap col-md-4 to col-sm-6

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen this question: [Boostrap 3 - col-md-4 to col-sm-6, or grid of 3x2 to 2x3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926617/boostrap-3-col-md-4-to-col-sm-6-or-grid-of-3x2-to-2x3)

But it hasn't worked for me.

This is my HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="services-offered">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
   <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
   <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Web Development</h3>
    <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
   <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
   <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Web App Development</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
   <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
   <div class="service-content">
    <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
   <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
   <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Web Development</h3>
    <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
   <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
   <div class="service-content">
    <h3>Web App Development</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
   <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
   <div class="service-content">
    <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>   
</div>
```

And the output can be seen [on this page](http://dev.shivampaw.com/me/) underneath the header (services section)

As you can see. The classes are `col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service` however it is position like this:

```
x  x  x
      x
x  x
```

When viewing on a `md` and above

How can this be fixed?

Comment: [This](http://www.bootply.com/lDkoetkMew)?

Comment: No. I know about that but if you look at the question I linked you will see why it doesn't work. That makes it so the col-sm-6 looks weird.  @BviLLe_Kid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1) Bootstrap 3

Use [responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets):

> With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a `.clearfix` and our [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

Don't forget to define `.clearfix` block for large devices too:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
```

Check the result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container services-offered">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web Development</h3>
                <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web App Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web Development</h3>
                <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web App Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

#### 2) PHP for Bootstrap 3

Check the counter on the multiplicity of the required number. Something like this:

```
<?php
  $counter = 0;
  if( have_posts() ){ while( have_posts() ){ the_post();
      if ($counter > 0) {
        $visible = '';
        if ($counter % 2 == 0) $visible .= ' visible-sm-block';
        if ($counter % 3 == 0) $visible .= ' visible-md-block visible-lg-block';
        if ($visible <> "") echo "<div class=\"clearfix" . $visible . "\"></div>\n";
      }
      echo "<div class=\"col-md-4 col-sm-6\">" . the_content() . "</div>\n";
      $counter++;
    }
  }
?>
```

#### 3) from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4

```
xs = sm
sm = md
md = lg
lg = xs

.visible-xs-block = .hidden-md-up
.hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up = .hidden-sm-down.hidden-lg-up
.visible-md-block = .hidden-md-down.hidden-xl-up
.visible-lg-block = .hidden-lg-down

.visible-xs-block.hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up = .hidden-lg-up
.visible-md-block.visible-lg-block = .hidden-md-down
```

So check the result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container services-offered">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web Development</h3>
                <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web App Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix hidden-md-down"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web Development</h3>
                <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>Web App Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 service">
            <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
            <div class="service-content">
                <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you think can give the logic? Because I am going to convert this into a WP theme which might have more than 6 items I need a way to make it all dynamic.

Comment: @Shiv Check the counter on the multiplicity of the required number. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! And I echo the actual "the_post" before the counter if statements right? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain - but do you have an answer for bootstrap 4 as well? I tried using `<div class="clearfix hidden-md-up hidden-md-down"></div>` for `%2 == 0` and `<div class="clearfix hidden-lg-down"></div>` for the 3 one but no luck.

Comment: Thanks! You are amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap uses floats to organize its column divs.  If a column div is a different height it won't be able to float all the way to the left.  In your example it looks like the first and second service divs are taller than the 3rd.  This is causing the second row to not be able to float left all the way.  The fix for this is to set a height on your columns that will be consistent and allow the `float:left` to float all the way to the left.  Something like

```
.service {
    height:200px;
}
```

view this codepen to see how the floats cause this:

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/PGRQYK

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two different rows to accomadate 6 columns.Try the below code,

```
<div class="services-offered">
<div class="row"> <!--1st row-->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
        <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
        <div class="service-content">
            <h3>Web Development</h3>
            <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
        <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
        <div class="service-content">
            <h3>Web App Development</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
        <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
        <div class="service-content">
            <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
  <div class='row'> <!--2nd row-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
        <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-code"></span></div>
        <div class="service-content">
            <h3>Web Development</h3>
            <p>My main area of expertise is in web development. I create professional looking websites at affordable prices. All of my websites come with speed, security and search engine optimisation as a standard.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
        <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-database"></span></div>
        <div class="service-content">
            <h3>Web App Development</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 service">
        <div class="service-icon"><span class="fa fa-5x fa-wordpress"></span></div>
        <div class="service-content">
            <h3>WordPress Development</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No. I know that but if you look at the question I linked you will see why it doesn't work. That makes it so the col-sm-6 looks weird.